# SQL Select Running Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
[RowNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnA ),
* 
FROM #Result ORDER BY ColumnA
```

This query give me running numbers according to ColumnA.

```
RowNumber   ColumnA     ColumnB
1           1597        ColB1
2           1597        ColB2

1           1602        ColB3
2           1602        ColB4
3           1602        ColB5
4           1602        ColB6

1           1603        ColB7
```

But what I want is like below result.

```
WhatIWant   ColumnA     ColumnB
1           1597        ColB1
1           1597        ColB2

2           1602        ColB3
2           1602        ColB4
2           1602        ColB5
2           1602        ColB6

3           1603        ColB7
```

So could someone explain me how I can change my query.

[Updated]

Thank to you all

- Allan S. Hansen
- Azad Chouhan
- Sunil Naudiyal
- Mahmoud Gamal

Because of your helpful suggestions, the problem is solved.

```
SELECT 
[RowNumber_Dense_Rank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ColumnA),
* 
FROM Result ORDER BY ColumnA
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d547c/28)

Comment: Try DENSE_RANK() instead of ROW_Number()

Answer (score 4):

Try this SQL Query

```
 SELECT 
[RowNumber] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA ),
* 
FROM #Result ORDER BY ColumnA
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
SELECT 
[RowNumber] = dense_rank() OVER ( ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnA ), * 
FROM #Result
ORDER BY ColumnA
```

More details about ranking functions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx).

Comment: This is not valid syntax for [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx), see [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d547c/21)